# The supremum axiom

Tags: definition, supremum-and-infimum

The axiom says: every nonnempty set bounded above has a supremum. In the case of $\{ q \in \mathbb{Q} \mid q^2\le2\}$ we do not have a supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$, but the one in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it necessary for the supremum to be in the same set? If so, why? The set I wrote here will be still bounded by $\sqrt{2}$, won't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb Q$, the set $\{q\in\mathbb Q\,|\,q^2\leqslant2\}$ has no supremum. In $\mathbb R$, it has one (which is $\sqrt2$).

Comment: That being said, the supremum _does_ have to belong to $\Bbb R$, where your set is a subset. In case that's what the OP meant.

Comment: @Arthur Let us wait for his or her comments.

Comment: I mean the point is that we work with rationals, and $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational. According to the definitions I've seen, we find upper bounds to the subset of a given set in the context of this set - so the sup has to be in $\mathbb{Q}$ here, too. At least, one source I know claims it has to be so. Still, I am asking myself is that necessary to find bounds in the same set...

Comment: @Kirill When we are working in $\mathbb Q$, the set $\{q\in\mathbb{Q}\,|\,q^2\leqslant2\}$ has no supremum. When we are working in $\mathbb R$, it has one (which is $\sqrt2$). It all depends on the ordered set that we are working with.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos we are in $\mathbb{Q}$. And that is the point. We are in $\mathbb{Q}$, but the set has a supremum in $\mathbb{R}$. Is that "bad" to look at the things this way? The set has a supremum, but in some other set. As $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ I do not think it is a crime to think so.

Comment: @Kirill Yes, it **is** bad to look at the things that way. We *must* state clearly what is the unverse that we are working in. When our universe is $\mathbb Q$, the set has no supremum and that's all.

Comment: Well, two sets are equal, if they have the same elements. The set I wrote in $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same we have in $\mathbb{R}$, no? If so, how can one set have and do not have s supremum at the same time?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so, that is actually what I wanted to know. It seems like bounds are something like complements - they make sence only referring to to universum.

Comment: @Kirill Because it's the same set in two different universes. Does $2$ have a multiplicative inverse? In $\mathbb Z$, no. In $\mathbb Q$, yes. But it's the same number.

Comment: @Kirill If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: no worries, @JoséCarlosSantos, I wanted to clarify some points here, as you do not answer on them in your post. You just say how it is, without explanation I have asked for. So, you do not answer the question, actually. But our conversation was very useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense to say only that a set $S$ has a supremum. What makes sense is to say that $S$ has a supremum **in** a specified universe $U$. In other words, having a supremum is not simply a property of a set but a property of a pair of sets $S$ and $U$. As you observed, one and the same $S$ (like $\{q\in\mathbb Q:q^2<2\}$) might have a supremum in one universe (like $\mathbb R$) and not have a supremum in another universe (like $\mathbb Q$).

(Admittedly, this is essentially the same answer that José Carlos Santos already gave, but I hope that, by making it a little longer, I've also made it easier to understand.)